# In react, how to take certain object property and store it in a different object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, is it possible to store certain properties from one object into another? For example, I have a form which allows me to enter multiple employees in different or same positions. In position 1 if I already have an active employee then I cannot add another employee to position 1 but can add it to other positions. If I want to add new employee to position one then I must provide end date for previously added employee in position 1.

The issue I am facing is that when I try to add another employee, for example, employee 2 for position 1 then the end date input that I am entering for employee 1 in employee 2 screen is getting stored in employee 2 object. For example, I need to store `activeEmployeeEndDate` from user 2 into user 1 object and remove it from user 2.

Any help I can get on this will be much appreciated.

[payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HQyg.png)

```
newPositions.map(employee => {
  employee.employees.map(emp => {
    if(emp.activeEmployeeEndDate) {
      let newUser = Object.assign({}, emp);
      newUser.activeEmployeeEndDate = emp.activeEmployeeEndDate
      console.log("newUser ", newUser)
      return newUser;  

    } 
    let currentUser = Object.assign({}, emp);
    currentUser.activeEmployeeEndDate = emp.activeEmployeeEndDate
    console.log("currentUser ", currentUser)
  })
})
```

[new payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBLuK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi As per your question

> For example, I need to store activeEmployeeEndDate from person 2 into
>   person 1 object and remove it from person 2.

The answer should be

```
person1.activeEmployeeEndDate = person2.activeEmployeeEndDate;
person2.activeEmployeeEndDate = null;
```

Comment: can you please provide your sample code so that I can reproduce it on my side?

Comment: I just updated my question with new snippet of code and a screenshot of the new payload. Your approach does worked out looks like but the only concern is the `undefined` value for activeEmployeeEndDate in currentUser. That for some reason is not getting stored.